# return scrambled sentence python

Tags: python-2.7, random, sentence

I am trying to write a code that will scramble the words in a sentence and return a string that is in a different order

```
from random import shuffle
def scramble():
  a=len("this is a sentence")
  for i in range(a):
random.shuffle("this is a sentence")
print(random.shuffle)
```

Not sure if I am even on the right track, however I believe the loop might be the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.shuffle` works on a a sequence, not a string. So first, use `str.split` to split the sentence into a list of words, call `shuffle` that, then turn it into a string again using `str.join`:

```
from random import shuffle

def scramble(sentence):
   split = sentence.split()  # Split the string into a list of words
   shuffle(split)  # This shuffles the list in-place.
   return ' '.join(split)  # Turn the list back into a string

print scramble("this is a sentence")
```

Output:

```
sentence a this is
```